# Get image description from Uri

Tags: android, image, uri

I m just trying to get image description from image uri

I already got the image (Bitmap) with this uri but I can't get the description of it

Its a pretty simple question. I hope you guys can help me :)

by "image description" I talking about what I wrote with this function: `insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imagePath, String name, String description)` (last arguement is what I want to get again (once its saved))

Comment: define `image description`

Comment: when you save a image you add a description to it (some text), in a image you have some informations like that. for instance here I m trying to get the description I wrote with this function "insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imagePath, String name, String description)" (last arguement)

Comment: you need to use `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html` and the `query` method. that will get you a cursor, in which you'll find the description, among other things.

Comment: well it doesn't help me much

Comment: what do you mean? you have the uri, you just need to query this uri to get the metadata columns.

Comment: how to get the description from the query? and what are the arguements for the query

Comment: I don't understand. there are 3 arguments. the first should be obvious, the second as well, and the third, well, if you want the description, then put there the name of the description column, which is indicated on the same page.

Comment: you'll need to learn to use cursors eventually if you write android applications. basically, you'll `cursor.moveToFirst()`, then `String desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I did:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION};
Cursor c = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(getContentResolver(),intent.getData(),projection);
c.moveToFirst();
String description = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION));
```